# Having trouble understanding a portion of code (bit operation)

Tags: c++, bit, bitwise-operators

I can't understand how to count number of 1's in binary representation.

I have my code, and I hope someone can explain it for me.

Code:

```
int count (int x)
{
    int nr=0;
    while(x != 0)
    {
        nr+=x%2;
        x/=2;
    }
    return nr;
}
```

1. Why `while` ? For example if i have `1011`, it wouldn't stop at 0?
2. Why `nr += x%2` ?
3. Why `x/=2` ?!

Comment: look at what these operations mean at a bit level.

Comment: Give me a link, i can't find anything

Comment: If you're in a position to change it, you probably should. This is a rather obfuscated way to work with bits.

Comment: @harold No, this is not an obfuscated way to work with bits. Do you know a more clear way to count the number of bits that are set in the binary representation of a number? I don't know any but I know more obfuscated ways to do it.

Comment: @axiac sure, with a right shift (on an unsigned integer) and a bitwise AND (ie the correct variant of Mihai's answer). It is clear then that it is extracting the bits and summing them. Of course that is still not an efficient way, but at least it doesn't use sneaky bit manipulation using operators that don't look like they have anything to do with bits.

Comment: @harold If you're taking about using arithmetic operators instead of bitwise operators then yes, that's not the right way to do it but it works well and as far as I know, the behaviour is guaranteed by the language. But about obfuscation... what about this code: `int count(int x) { for (int nb = 0; x; x &= x-1, nb ++); return nb; }`? ;-)

Comment: @axiac ah yes, using the old "reset the lowest set bit"-trick, probably tricky for many people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:**

```
nr += x % 2;
```

Imagine x in binary:

```
...1001101
```

The Modulo operator returns the remainder from a / b.

Now the last bit of x is either a 0, in which case 2 will always go into x with 0 remainder, or a 1, in which case it returns a 1.

As you can see x % 2 will return (if the last bit is a one) a one, thus incrementing nr by one, or not, in which case nr is unchanged.

```
x /= 2;
```

This divides x by two, and because it is a integer, drops the remainder. What this means is is the binary was

```
....10
```

It will find out how many times 2 would go into it, in this case 1. It effectively drops the last digit of the binary number because in base 2 (binary) the number of times 2 goes into a number is just the same as 'shifting' everything down a space (This is a poor explanation, please ask if you need elaboration). This effectively 'iterates' through the binary number, allowing the line about to check the next bit.

This will iterate until the binary is just `1` and then half that, drop the remainder and x will equal 0,

```
while (x != 0)
```

in which case exit the loop, you have checked every bit.

**Also:**

'count`is possibly not the most descriptive name for a function, consider naming it something more descriptive of its purpose.

nr will always be a integer greater or equal to zero, so you should probably have the return type `unsigned int`

Comment: Maybe `count` is not very descriptive but it expresses what the function does: it counts the bits that are set in the binary representation of its argument.

Comment: True, maybe `unsigned int CountPosBits (int x)`

Answer (score 1):

```
int count (int x)
{
    int nr=0;
    while(x != 0)
    {
        nr+=x%2;
        x/=2;
    }
    return nr;
}
```

This program basically gives the numbers of set bits in a given integer.

For instance, lets start with the example integer 11 ( binary representation - `1011`).
First flow will enter the `while` loop and check for the number, if it is equal to zero.
`while(11 != 0)`

Since `11` is not equal to zero it enter the `while` loop and `nr` is assigned the value 1 (11%2 = 1).`nr += 11%2;`
Then it executes the second line inside the loop (x = x/2). This line of code assigns the value `5 (11/2 = 5 )` to `x`.

Once done with the body of the `while` loop, it then again checks if `x` ie 5 is equal to zero.
`while( 5 != 0)`.
Since it is not the case,the flow goes inside the `while` loop for the second time and  `nr` is assigned the value `2 ( 1+ 5%2)`. 
After that the value of `x` is divided by 2 (x/2, 5/2 = 2 )and it assigns 2 to `x`. 
Similarly in the next loop, `while (2 != 0 )`,  `nr` adds (2 + 2%2), since 2%2 is 0, value of `nr` remains 2 and value of `x` is decreased to 1 (2/2) in the next line. 
1 is not eqaul to 0 so it enters the while loop for the third time.

In the third execution of the while loop `nr` value is increased to 3  (2 + 1%2).
After that value of `x` is reduced to 0  ( `x = 1/2 which is 0`).

Since it fails the check `(while x != 0)`, the flow comes out of the loop.

At the end the value of `nr` (Which is the number of bits set in a given integer) is returned to the calling function.

Best way to understand the flow of a program is executing the program through a debugger. I strongly suggest you to execute the program once through a debugger.It will help you to understand the flow completely.